# Call two function inside a class based view - Django

Tags: python, django

I have a class connected to a template, inside it I have two functions, one is to authenticate the user (using credentials available in my db) and the second one is to actually get some data and push it to my template. However using `print('whatever')` I see that neither function gets called when I call the class. Why?

`views.py`

```
class GenerateReport(TemplateView): # This view is responsable to access users data and return it
    template_name = 'ga_app/report.html'
    def generate_report(request): # authenticate user
        c = CredentialsModel.objects.get(user_id = request.user.id)
        credentials = c.credentials
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credentials.authorize(http)
        service = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', http=http)
        print('This first function is not called')

    def print_data(request): # Get some data
        profile_id = GoogleProperty.objects.get(user_id = request.user.id)
        some_data = service.data().ga().get(
          ids='ga:' + profile_id,
          start_date='7daysAgo',
          end_date='today',
          metrics='ga:sessions').execute()
        print('This second function neither')
        return render(request, self.report, {'some_data': some_data}, {'profile_id': profile_id})
```

`urls.py`

```
url(r'^re/$', GenerateReport.as_view(), name='re'),
```

The shell obviously doesn't show anything printed out, and the template doesn't render `metrics` and/or `profile_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions will not be called by default, so you need to call them yourself. Looking at the documentation for [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView) it looks like you would need to implement a `get_context_data` method, where you can call those functions, and return a context for your template.